# could you help me with a sed command to search for a string "ABC = 0x000" in a line and perform positional replacement of zeros in the string

Tags: sed

I have a string "ABC = 0x0000" in a line and want to perform positional replacement of any of the zeros with x.
I want to extract "ABC = 0x000" from the line containing this string and replace zeros at certain positions with x could be replace position 1 and 3 with or 2 and 4 etc. i would prefer performing these operations in place (i.e using -i option as i dont want a file to  be created).

Any  help would be appreciated.

i tried using the command sed -r 's/(ABC )/' file.csv . it gives this error
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command

i first want to extract ABC = 0x000 from this line then perform position replacement in string "0x0000". ABC = 0x0000 may have more number of characters as well.

```
awdgb, ade nnm , ars, qwe: yur ABC = 0x0000
```

then perform positional replacement of zeros.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Using `-i` will not prevent a new file from being created.  It will just hide the creation of the new file from you.  Do you actually want to ensure that no new file is created, or do you just want to pretend that no new file is being created?  If the latter, then `-i` will (probably) work just fine for you.

Comment: -i is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(\S+ = 0x)(\S+)/\1\n\2\n/
        h
        s/[^\n]*\n//
        s/\n.*//
        s/./a/1
        s//a/3
        s//b/2
        s//b/4
        H
        g
        s/\n.*\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' file
```

Insert newline delimiters before and after the string to be amended.

Make a copy of the line with the delimiters.

Remove the part of the line before and after the delimiters.

Replace the characters as you please, using an index for each character staring from 1.

Append the result to the original line.

Replace the current line with the original line with the result appended.

Replace the original string with ameliorated one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```bash
sed -E 's/ABC = (0)x(0)(0)(0)(0)/ABC = \1x\2\3\4\5/g' myfile
```

Here every zero of your string captured inseparate group `\1` through `\5`, and can be replaced as you wish.

Example of replacement `0x0000` with `0xab00` would be expression `s/ABC = (0)x(0)(0)(0)(0)/ABC = \1xab\4\5/g`

I advise you test sed without `-i` switch, achieve desired output and only use `-i` once you satisfied with output.

---

Error in your attempt is caused by lack of replacement string. `s` commands require three delimiters: `s/pattern/replacement/flags`.

Closest valid command to your attempt would be `s/ABC //`: it will replace first appearance of `ABC`  with empty string.

Comment: Closest valid command to your attempt would be s/ABC //: it will replace first appearance of ABC  with empty string. i tried this yes it was replaced with an empty string.

Comment: is there a  way i can extract only ABC = 0x0000 from the line and use the command  sed -e 's/\(.\{3\}\)./\1x/' file.csv to replace positions in the string with x.

Comment: @Divya, what exactly should be in the output?

Comment: captured string ABC = 0x0000 should be replaced with 'x' at certain positions. final output should be ABC = 0x00xx or ABC = 0xx00 any of these

Comment: @Divya, `s/ABC = 0x(0)(0)(0)(0)/ABC = 0x\1\2xx/g` for the first one, and `s/ABC = 0x(0)(0)(0)(0)/ABC = 0xxx\3\4/g` second (assuming you meant `0xxx00`)

Comment: the replacement part is fine. i just want a command to extract ABC = 0x0000 from the line . im not able to extract that . i need a sed command to extract ABC=0x0000  from ABC, lldggd, ABC = 0x0000

Comment: @Divya, please edit your question and add example of what you have right now (full line, as text!) and what you expect it to be n result.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v poss='1 3' '
    BEGIN { split(poss,ps) }
    match($0,/ABC = [^ ]+/) {
        s = RSTART + 6
        for (i in ps) {
            $0 = substr($0,1,s-2+ps[i]) "x" substr($0,s+ps[i])
        }
    }
    { print }
' file
awdgb, ade nnm , ars, qwe: yur ABC = xxx000
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v poss='1 3' '
    BEGIN { split(poss,ps) }
    match($0,/ABC = [^ ]+/) {
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        for (i in ps) {
            $0 = substr($0,1,6+ps[i]-1) "x" substr($0,6+ps[i]+1)
        }
    }
    { print }
' file
ABC = xxx000
```